# Why is my "explicit operator bool()" not called?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean, type-conversion, explicit-conversion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        return true;
    }

    operator int()
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    if (A())
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
}
```

My expectation was that `A()` would be contextually converted to `bool` using my `operator bool()`, and therefore print `true`.

However, the output is `false`, showing that `operator int()` was invoked instead.

Why is my `explicit operator bool` not called as expected?

Comment: I expect the output is true. However, the real output is `false` rather than `true`!

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: @xmllmx You haven't elaborated anything.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because `A()` is not `const`, the `operator int()` is selected. Just add `const` to the other conversion operator and it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    explicit operator bool() const
    {
        std::cout << "bool: ";
        return true;
    }

    operator int() const
    {
        std::cout << "int: ";
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    if (A())
    {
        cout << "true" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "false" << endl;
    }
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7438901e71fdc947) that prints: "bool: true" and without the `const` it prints "int: false"

Alternatively, make a named constant:

```
// operator int() without const

int main()
{
    auto const a = A();

    if (a)
    // as before
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26b10d577c0f2f03) that prints "bool: true".

Comment: @downvoter: please elaborate so that I can improve my anwswer!

Comment: There's a third alternative (though I don't recommend it), which is to provide a non-const overload of `operator bool()`.